# Where to access IBOutlet var and use it to define a constant accessible to the class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, iboutlet

I read that I should wait until the view loads (or `viewDidLoad()`) before trying to access properties of an `IBOutlet`.

My problem is: I want to store the title color property of an `IBOutlet` UIButton as a constant that is accessible to the entire ViewController class, or at least from an `IBAction` method within the class- but it seems that that is out of scope since I'm defining the constant inside `viewDidLoad()` and I am unable to access it anywhere else. I need to use it in both `viewDidLoad()` and in an `IBAction` method.

I can't define it outside of any class methods because I get an error saying `Instance member 'lowFilterButton' cannot be used on type ViewController` so what should I do? I could hardcode the colour into both methods but I want to find a better solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are try to access a class constant in an instance method (`viewDidLoad()`) without the proper reference. Class constants belong to the class, not the instance so you can't write:

```
color = ...      // invalid
self.color = ... // invalid
```

Do this instead:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    static var color: UIColor!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Refer to the class of the current instance
        self.dynamicType.color = myButton.tintColor

        // You can also refer to the class by name
        ViewController.color = myButton.tintColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to easily access a constant color, define it before `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
let myColor = UIcolor.[NAME OF COLOR]
```

Then when you want to set the button's color, do so like this:

```
lowFilterButton.tintColor = myColor
```

As long as you define myColor outside of viewDidLoad, you should be able to access it throughout the view controller.

Comment: My question was about defining that first constant myColor by accessing an IBOutlet's property (not just UIcolor) which does not work outside a method. It was answered below though! Thanks anyway